# objective c show NSDictionary value in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary, uialertview

i have a  NSDictionary and my NSDictionary is bellow .

```
 NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
```

and NSMutableDictionary out is :

```
{
    "access-numbers" =     (
                {
            "access-number" = 8822114477;
            "toll-free" = 0;
        },
                {
            "access-number" = 4353;
            "toll-free" = 1;
        }
    );
    "area-prefix" = "-1";
    "country-prefix" = 880;
    status = 200;
}
```

i want to show in UIAlertView `"access-number" = 8822114477;` and `"access-number" = 4353;`

For now i cover it like this way

```
  NSString *telAcceesNumber=[[jsonDic valueForKeyPath:@"access-numbers"][0] objectForKey:@"access-number"];
    NSString *tolfree=[[jsonDic valueForKeyPath:@"access-numbers"][1] objectForKey:@"access-number"];
```

and show on UIAlertView

```
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Accesss Number"
                                                        message:Nil
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:telAcceesNumber,tolfree,nil];
        [alert show];
```

But i am want get my both access-number using for-loop and display on UIAlertView . Because of sometimes may be access-number will be only once or more then three times .

would you kindly help to solve my problem .

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are plenty of question about parsing JSON. What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried and what did not work for you? You have to come up with a problem for people to help you, not just ask people how to do this without trying anything yourself.

Comment: @halileohalilei you get my question not only that you also don't want to share your know knowledge .

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan I actually don't get your question, that's why I asked "what have you tried and what did not work for you". From my point of view, you look like you're trying to get people to write your code for you without trying to solve the problem by yourself. If you provide the stuff I asked about, I would be more than happy to help you.

Comment: Just retrieve the "access-numbers" array in an NSArray object and then you can iterate it for whatever you want to do with it. I don't see any difficulty here.

Comment: If you can't figure out a basic scheme to deal with this you're not programmer material.  One might encounter specific problems with the implementation (which it's fair to ask about here), but you should be able to figure out a general approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the values you wish from the dictionary with the key "access-numbers" using this piece of code:

```
NSMutableArray *allAccessNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *accessNumbers = jsonDict[@"access-numbers"];
for (NSDictionary *current in accessNumbers)
{
    NSString *accessNumber = current[@"access-number"];
    [allAccessNumbers addObject:accessNumber];
}
```

Later on, you can build your `NSString` to show in your alert view using the values of `allAccessNumbers`. You can even build the `NSString` inside the `for` loop if you won't need each access number individually in the future. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to construct an `NSString` in such a way that it should get both keys and values and the next-Line `\n`.

```
NSString *displayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ \n",key, [jsonArray valueForKey:key]];
```

And add more key values to it. Once you do that, you can easily show this in a `UIAlertController`.

Comment: i am want get my both access-number using for-loop and display on UIAlertView . Because of sometimes may be access-number will be only once or more then three times .. did you get my point . Would kind help me to solve my problem .